# How to receive BufferSize from Client to Server?

Tags: c#, client-server, file-transfer, tcp

My Server Class:

```
namespace Net_Send_File
{
    class Server
    {


        private TcpListener listener;
        private IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 15550);
        private bool active;
        string  arg;
       // private Socket xxx;

        public Server()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Title = "Server";
            Main();
        }

        private void Main()
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(ipep);

            try
            {
                listener.Start();
                active = true;

                ListenForConnections();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }

        private void ListenForConnections()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for connections...");

            while (active)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Connection @ {0}", TCPIP(client));

                new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientData)).Start(client);

            }
        }

        private void HandleClientData(object _c)
        {
            TcpClient c = (TcpClient)_c;
            string ipaddr = TCPIP(c);

            NetworkStream s = c.GetStream();
            // I tried this byte[] buffer = new byte[c.ReceiveBufferSize]; It throws an Exeption. 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;

            while (active)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {

                        bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length/2);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Socket error @ {0}:\r\n{1}", ipaddr, ex.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected @ {0}", ipaddr);
                    //new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart.ListenForConnections);
                    break;
                }

                string dataStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                using (var fs = File.OpenWrite("test.txt"))
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private string TCPIP(TcpClient c)
        {
            return ((IPEndPoint)c.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
        }

    };
```

My Client Class:

```
        class Client
    {
        private TcpClient client;
       // private TcpClient client1;
        private IPEndPoint ipep;
        private int port;


        public Client()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Title = "Client";
            bool error = false;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IPEndPoint: ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!input.Contains(':'))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IPEndPoint in bad format");
                    break;
                }

                string[] s1 = input.Split(':');
                IPAddress ipaddr;

                if (!IPAddress.TryParse(s1[0], out ipaddr) || !int.TryParse(s1[1], out port))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IPEndPoint in bad format");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    error = true;
                    break;
                }

                ipep = new IPEndPoint(ipaddr, port);

                try
                {
                    client = new TcpClient();
                    client.Connect(ipep);
                    Console.WriteLine("client 1 is Ready!");

                    //client1 = new TcpClient();
                    //client1.Connect(ipep);
                    //Console.WriteLine("client 2 is Ready!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect\r\nReason: {0}", ex.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    error = true;
                }

                break;
            }

            while (!error)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("File path: ");
                string filePath = Console.ReadLine();

                if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File does not exist\r\nPress ENTER to try again");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                byte[] buffer;
                using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                {
                    buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    Int64 a = client.SendBufferSize; ;
                    fs.Close();
                }

                if (SendData(buffer))
                {
               // client.SendBufferSize(buffer);

                    //int a = client.SendBufferSize; ;

                    Console.WriteLine("File sent\r\nFile size: {0} KB", (buffer.Length / 1024));


                    //a.SetLength((buffer.Length / 1024));

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        private bool SendData(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
                {
                    ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    ns.Close();
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to send file\r\nReason: {0}\r\nDetailed:\r\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

First of all accept my apologise for my code is badly commented. Or to be honest no comments at all, almost.

Server class, under the method called `private void HandleClient Data(object _)` I have a buffer. Buffer is set to byte[1024]. I want to receive bufferSize (of my test file) from client, set Server buffer = to ClientBuffer and there after receive file. I have a test file which is 60MB. I tried to send my buffer size from client to server but it doesn't work well. Can someone tell me what I can do and how?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement an application level protocol, for example:

```
MESSAGE:
    [SIZE (8 BYTES)][DATA (SIZE BYTES)]
```

Then, use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`

```
//client
var writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
FileInfo fileInfoToSend = new FileInfo(path);
long fileSize = fileInfoToSend.Length;
writer.Write(fileSize);
using (FileStream fileStream = fileInfoToSend .Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
{    
    fileStream.CopyTo(writer.BaseStream);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

---

```
//server
var stream = c.GetStream();
var reader = new BinaryReader(c.GetStream());
FileInfo fileInfoToWrite = new FileInfo(path);
long fileSize = reader.ReadInt64();
using (FileStream fileStream = fileInfoToWrite.Create()) 
{    
    int read = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < fileSize; i += (long)read)
    {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(fileSize - i, 1024));
       if (read == 0)
          return;//client disconnected!(or throw Exception)
       fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

*untested*

Comment: I should or I must? Are there anyother ways to do this?

Comment: You can use serialization if your file is small.

Comment: Any time a file is sent or recieved, 60 more mb of memory are used by the app.

Comment: Yes that I understand, but my question stays the same. you said "serialization if file is small". What is small, are we talking kb mb gb ? :)